# How can I push the elements into array in a desired format

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I would like to push the elements into an array in   a desired format 
My code is :

```
 var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.reportRangeList.length; i++)
    {
     arr.push($scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName  , $scope.reportRangeList[i].total1);
     alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }
```

where `$scope.reportRangeList` is a JSON dynamic object

for the above the code i got the output like :

```
[
    "abc",1820,
    "pqrs",2349.67

 ]
```

Now i want to display the output like :

```
[
    "abc",1820
],

 [    "pqrs",2349.67

 ]
```

Please help me to display output in a desired format in java script or angular or j query .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired format

```
var first = $scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName,
    second = $scope.reportRangeList[i].total1,
    text;

arr.push([first, second]);

text = JSON.stringify(arr); 
text = text.substring(1, text.length - 1);
alert(text);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40b1mkgL/2/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,your JSFiddle explains the output,good logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can push an array like

```
arr.push([$scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName  , $scope.reportRangeList[i].total1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,I tried with your answer it seems like very near approach ,the out put is :
[
  [
    "abc",1820
  ],

  [    "pqrs",2349.67

  ]
]
I managed the extra braces in internal code ,if possible can you make it desired format.

Comment: @user3812457 what you have is an array of arrays... if you want to remove the `[]` wrapper then you need to convert the array to a string then remove the wrapping `[]`

Answer (score 1):

For that format push an array every time like bellow

```
arr.push([$scope.reportRangeList[i].businessName  , $scope.reportRangeList[i].total1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,I tried with your answer it seems like very near approach ,the out put is : [ [ "abc",1820 ], [ "pqrs",2349.67 ] ] I managed the extra braces in internal code ,if possible can you make it desired format.